# selfupdate macports not working

Tags: macos, osx-lion, macports

suddently macports is not working though it use too, am getting the below error

```
Mos-MacBook-Pro:Projects mo$ sudo port -d selfupdate
Warning: port definitions are more than two weeks old, consider using selfupdate
--->  Updating the ports tree
DEBUG: Synchronizing ports tree(s)
Synchronizing local ports tree from rsync://rsync.macports.org/release/ports/
DEBUG: /usr/bin/rsync -rtzv --delete-after '--exclude=/PortIndex*' rsync://rsync.macports.org/release/ports/ /opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/ports

@ERROR: chdir failed
rsync error: error starting client-server protocol (code 5) at /SourceCache/rsync/rsync-42/rsync/main.c(1398) [receiver=2.6.9]
shell command "/usr/bin/rsync -rtzv --delete-after '--exclude=/PortIndex*' rsync://rsync.macports.org/release/ports/ /opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/ports" returned error 5
Error: Synchronization of the local ports tree failed doing rsync
DEBUG: Couldn't sync the ports tree: Synchronization of 1 source(s) failed
    while executing
"macports::selfupdate [array get global_options] base_updated"
Error: /opt/local/bin/port: port selfupdate failed: Couldn't sync the ports tree: Synchronization of 1 source(s) failed
```

the macports use to work few months ago, but since i upgraded to lion it stopped. I don't know if it is related to the upgrade or not, today i tried to troubleshoot it but got no where. I thought of reinstalling but i cannot find the dmg for lion on their site (broken link).

Comment: It looks like the directory `/opt/local/macports` is missing?  If so you'll need to reinstall MacPorts.

Comment: yup its missing, but i cannot find dmg on their site. All download links are broken, is there a different source?

Comment: I doubt it.  I guess it'll be up shortly...

Comment: Ugh. Pissed that all their download links are borked. Glad that your posts are from only hours ago. All MacPorts is dukka.

Comment: hi, i just reinstalled macports from subversion and i still get the same error :S

Comment: @beOn, the subversion is up, you can clone the source and compile it. Other than that, everything is down.

Comment: @MoJ.Mughrabi wound up checking out home brew. It's pretty shibby.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now , macports's rsync server is down see https://trac.macports.org/ticket/34298